# What exactly are convex constraints?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question, seek an answer from a professor or figure it out myself as I am not a mathematics expert. I used the `nonlinear-optimization` but I'm not sure this is specific enough, so I invite you to add more correct tags.
I have a specific problem, but I'll try to phrase it more generally: **What are convex constraints?** Here's the frame of my problem.

Consider a non-convex quadratic optimization problem, with the following cost function, where **X** is given:

$$\|\textbf{X} - \textbf{XCS}\|_F^2$$

subject to constraints $|\textbf{c}_j|_1 = 1\,\, \forall \,\, j \in \{0, ..., k\}$ and $|\textbf{s}_i|_1 = 1 \,\, \forall \,\, i \in \{0, ..., n\}$ and "all coefficients in $\textbf{C}$ and $\textbf{S}$ are positive".
Furthermore, $\textbf{X} = [\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2, ..., \textbf{x}_n] \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\textbf{S} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and $\textbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$.

I can show that my problem is non-convex by showing that the Hessian is not positive semi-definite, but how do I show that my constraints are convex? What does it mean to the optimization problem that they are. What does it mean that they aren't?

Comment: Convex constraints means that your constraint set is a convex set. See something like Boyd and Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization for details.

Comment: Linear inequalities are convex, since they prescribe solutions to lie in a "half-space" (which is always a convex set).  If $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a convex function, then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \le C$ is a convex constraint for any constant $C$.  One may need care to show that a convex constraint (or indeed a constraint of any kind) admits feasible solutions (that region satisfying the constraint is not empty).